# Exporting compressed video

Tags: ros, image-transport, video, compressed, extract-images

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed the linked image and video data export tutorial:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbag/Tutorials/Exporting%20image%20and%20video%20data

However, I only save the compressed video to the bag file. From the following warning and error, I can see that I set an incorrect topic `/gscam/image_raw/compressed`, however, `/gscam/image_raw` only obviously would not work because only the compressed topic is published.

`[ WARN] [1314815531.598786851]: [image_transport] It looks like you are trying to subscribe directly to a transport-specific image topic '/gscam/image_raw/compressed', in which case you will likely get a connection error. Try subscribing to the base topic '/gscam/image_raw' instead with parameter ~image_transport set to 'compressed' (on the command line, _image_transport:=compressed). See http://ros.org/wiki/image_transport for details.`

`[ERROR] [1314815532.042773170]: Client [/extract] wants topic /gscam/image_raw/compressed to have datatype/md5sum [sensor_msgs/Image/060021388200f6f0f447d0fcd9c64743], but our version has [sensor_msgs/CompressedImage/8f7a12909da2c9d3332d540a0977563f]. Dropping connection`

My question is, how can I specify to export the compressed video stream?

Many Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11118/exporting-compressed-video/) by [Charence](https://answers.ros.org/users/908/charence/) on ROS Answers with karma: 137 on 2011-09-05

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This should work:

```
$ rosrun image_view extract_images image:=/gscam/image_raw _image_transport:=compressed
```

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5